# How much iron ore could a medieval miner extract per day?

Tags: middle-ages, economy, metallurgy, industry

I am finding really hard to find an answer to this question. There are some numbers available online, but first of all the numbers range quite a lot from different sources, then they are given for a whole mine (without mentioning how many miners would work there) and then it's also hard to find related references.

I am looking in particular for numbers for Europe in the 1400s (in general between 1300 and 1500). So, what's the best estimate for how much iron ore (in kg) could a medieval miner in this period extract per day on average?

Some of the sources I already looked at:

- https://www.mdpi.com/2075-163X/11/10/1136
- https://acoup.blog/2020/09/18/collections-iron-how-did-they-make-it-part-i-mining/
- Wikipedia/britannica/quora

Comment: There are different types of iron ore that will yield different amounts of iron. Iron ore mining methods vary by the type of ore being mined. The middle-ages spans about a thousand years and technology changed over that time. So your answer will vary by location and by period.

Comment: Miners extract iron *ore*, with an iron content anywhere from 30% to 70% iron in deposits that have been worked historically. Is the question asking about the amount of iron ore a miner could extract per day, or is it asking about the amount of pure iron contained in it, which varies by the quality of the ore deposit? The amount of ore extracted per miner depended on available technology and the specifics of mining (i.e. hardness of surrounding rock, depth of mines) so could vary widely. It therefore seems advisable to limit the question to a specific region and century.

Comment: Leigh Bettenay, "Geological and Mining Constraints on Historical Mine Production: The Case of Early Medieval Lead-Silver Mining at Melle, France," *Metalla*, Vol. 26, No. 2, August 2022, pp. 67-86, contains an overview of estimated daily rock / ore extraction rates (kg/miner/day)  for various locales and time periods in table 2. Nothing specifically for iron ore mining, and some ranges vary widely, but maybe the sources cited can provide some starting points for further exploration of the literature.

Comment: This looks to be an X-Y question: A question ostensibly asking about X, when it is in fact only seeking X in order to infer an answer to Y based on an, often erroneous, assumption by OP. So, please explain why the daily output of a single miner is of such import when it is in fact meaningless due to variations in mine type (pit or strip), ore quality, access to water-dirven mechanical energy, depth of mine-face, etc. For this time period, from Newcastle to Silesia, availability and cost is limited by charcoal access, not iron-ore supply.

Comment: [Statistical Inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method#Statistical_inference) and [Argument from Analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method#Argument_from_analogy) are principles used within the [Historical Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method), so inferring 'an answer to Y' is often an important part of trying to understand History.

Comment: Let's be generous and assume that the question is about *average* productivity of a miner, and that the questioner understands that there will be significant variations.

Comment: Thanks for you comments and suggestions. I edited the question to add more details and clarify some doubts. Indeed I am asking about average estimates. An aggregate value is also acceptable, for example for an entire mine or even country, as long as it clearly indicates the period (e.g. 1 year) of such aggregate value and how many mines/workers per mine was it aggregated for, so that I can then get an average value pro capita. I am not sure what you mean @Pieter Geerkens, I do not intend to infer an answer to Y question otherwise I would have asked Y question!

Comment: @Redirectk: Simply put: for the period of interest, productivity of a mine, and of its miners, was limited solely and quite strictly by the availability of charcoal. The great forests of Europe were already starting to disappear, and no where more rapidly than in the close vicinity of iron mines. In many ways, the productivity of miners is completely irrelevant: there was far more than enough ore - but not enough charcoal.